# "Add to Outlook" option for individual events in SPO site

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, events

We have an Events/Calendar list in SPO site.

The user wanted an option to add individual events to their Outlook calendar(not the entire Event list)

That is each event should have a column called "Add to Outlook" clicking on which that particular event/item should be added to the users' outlook calendar.

This way, the users can add only the events/items they are interested in to their outlook calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the classic view, there is a button in the ribbon under Custom Commands that will download an ICS file for a specific event:

[image]

In a modern view, this is gone. But you can still generate the link in the same way. The link is in the format:

**[WebURL]**/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&&Cmd=Display&List={**[ListGUID]**}&CacheControl=1&ID=**[EventListItemID]**&Using=event.ics

You can create that link in a variety of ways but here's an example using column formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "AddEvent",
    "class": "ms-fontSize-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover",
    "title": "Add to my calendar",
    "href": "=@currentWeb + '/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={0544b2e4-0101-4c19-ac53-b7839c91b025}&CacheControl=1&ID=' + [$ID] + '&Using=event.ics'"
  },
  "style": {
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "text-decoration": "none"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, we don't have access to the List GUID in list formatting, so that bit is hardcoded.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Many thanks.. but all the events are getting downloaded as owssvr.ics, possible to get it downloaded as "Eventtitle.ics"?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't believe there's a way to customize the filename 