# Calendar Web Part - change 'join' button to 'add to calendar'

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, calendar-view

Not sure if this is possible. In the standard calendar web part, the event details are shown alongside a 'join' button for team meetings. The way we're using this calendar is as a notice of upcoming events, so the primary use will be to see something you're interested in and then add it to your calendar, rather than to join the meeting straight away.

Is it possible to change the view so the 'join' button is an 'add to calendar' button instead?

I'm aware users can add to calendar by opening the event up, just trying to make it easier and more obvious for people.

I'm very much a point and click user, so would appreciate an answer for dummies!

Many thanks for any help.

Edit to add image:
[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of "Join" button you are talking about if possible? Edit your original question and then attach screenshot.

Comment: Also, check if this helps: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306286/add-to-outlook-option-for-individual-events-in-spo-site

Comment: thanks, I've added an image now - I had a look at that link and don't think it solves my questions - but that could just be that I don't understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you provided, it is a button in the modern calendar web part. Until now, it is not supported to make changes for the button of modern calendar web part.